# Django-Ajax passing multiple parameters

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to get more details on clicking a button "type="button" class="apireq"" defined on each row and capture the result in javascript and show it in a window 
I am not able to get the clicked row data in jquery .It says variable value undefined .I wanted to POST multiple values . Is this the way to do it ? Do I need to modify urls.py

### template

```html
<tbody id="collist"></tbody>
  </tr>   
     {% for index, row in s_results.iterrows %} 
  <tr>
    <td> {{ row.colname }} </td> <td> {{ row.dbname }} </td> <td> {{ row.schemaname }} </td> <td> {{ row.tablenm }} </td>
          <td> {{ row.coltype }} </td> <td> {{ row.collength }} </td> <td> {{ row.colscale }} </td>      
          <td>  <input type="button" class="apireq" 
    data-colname="{{row.colname}}"
    data-dbname="{{row.dbname}}"
    data-schemaname="{{row.schemaname}}"
    data-tablenm="{{row.tablenm}}" /> </td>
  <tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

### js/app.js

```js
$('.apireq').click(function () {
        var jq_column_name = $("#collist tr").last().attr("data-colname");
        alert(jq_column_name);
        var jq_dbname = $("#collist tr").last().attr("data-dbname");
        var jq_schemaname = $("#collist tr").last().attr("data-schemaname");
        var jq_tablenm = $("#collist tr").last().attr("data-tablenm");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:8000/refresh1/",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: { column_name: jq_column_name, db_name: jq_dbname, schema_name: jq_schemaname, table_name: jq_tablenm },
            success: function (data) {
            alert("success!!");},
            error: alert("Failed!!")
            });});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

urls.py

path('refresh////', views.refresh1, name='refresh1'),

Comment: First issue resolved . var jq_column_name = $(this).attr('data-colname'); works . Now working on how to pass multiple values with the url

Comment: You can encode the data with jquery before you send it, https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_serialize.asp

Comment: That also resolved .